# Properties inside generic class. get property in Find of Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, reflection

I am using this class:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    ...
    public string culture { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and this **function**:

```
object getData<T>() 
{
   var res = GetCollection<T>().Find(x => x.culture == "ca-ES").ToList()

   return res;
}
```

calling it as `getData<MyClass>()`

**GetCollection** function is but it is working, then it is not the problem:

```
private IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>()
{
    db.GetCollection<T>("myclass");
}
```

My problem is that the function I am using inside find a comparison to get that rss by culture. The compiler give me an error. That property is inside other classes with the same name.

**Json** of myclass in mongo is:

```
[
    {
      "culture": "ca-ES", ...
    },
    {
      "culture": "es-ES", ...
    },
    {
      "culture": "en-GB", ...
    }
]
```

In the example should return:

```
{
    "culture": "ca-ES", ...
}
```

How can I resolve it to compare by culture?

Comment: yes, it shoud return myclass in the culture I choiced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the types that can be used so that the compiler knows that a `culture` property exists:

```
object getData<T>() where T : MyClass
{
   var res = GetCollection<T>().Find(x => x.culture == "ca-ES").ToList();

   return res;
}
```

This isn't terribly useful though, since now `getData` can only work with `MyClass` or descendants.

You should either remove the generic parameter, if you are only interested in `MyClass`:

```
object getData()
{
   var res = GetCollection<MyClass>().Find(x => x.culture == "ca-ES").ToList();

   return res;
}
```

Or define some base class/interface that has a `culture` property:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    string culture { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : ISomeInterface

object getData<T>() where T : ISomeInterface
{
   var res = GetCollection<T>().Find(x => x.culture == "ca-ES").ToList();

   return res;
}
```

As a side note, notice that in none of the cases above you should be returning `object` when you could use `List<T> getData<T>()` or `List<MyClass> getData()`

Comment: true, I didn't thought in heritance ,,, ir interfaces. I was thinking only in reflection way but your solution is right... Thx,